# Designing database with Filename, Testname and its result on every build

Tags: c#, database, database-design

I have to design a database where I have to store `Test Name` for each `Filename` and Each `Test Name` can run on several `Builds` and can either `Pass` or `Fail`.
There is 1-1 relationship between `Filename` & `Test Name`, which means there is one 1 file for 1 test. But each test can run on many builds and can have different outputs.

My approach is:
Table 1: **FileAndTestMap**

```
+----------+----------+
| Testname | Filename |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | A.txt    |
+----------+----------+
| 2        | Er.txt   |
+----------+----------+
```

Table 2: **Build**

```
+------+--------------+
| S No | Build Number |
+------+--------------+
| 1    | Build_123    |
+------+--------------+
| 2    | Build_234    |
+------+--------------+
```

Table 3: **Build_XXX** *(For each build)*

```
+----------+----------+--------+
| TestName | Executed | Passed |
+----------+----------+--------+
| 1        | Y        | Y      |
+----------+----------+--------+
| 2        | N        | N      |
+----------+----------+--------+
```

I do not like this design and need a better approach to this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why won't you use foreign keys?

Comment: I don't actually have any prior experience in the area nor have I any in-depth knowledge on it. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decide database mappings based on the persistence of entities i.e, whether your entity can persist independently or not. In your case specifically, following are standalone and dependent entities:

1. File Name > Standalone. File can persist even when there will be no test or build.
2. Test Name > Dependent. Test name can exist only if file exists and build exist. And each test name belongs to one and only one file name.
3. Build > partially dependent on file. You can build when there is at least a file

So, now you can get started by database mapping like this:

FileName

```
 +----------+----------
| Id       | Filename |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | A.txt    |
+----------+----------+
| 2        | Er.txt   |
+----------+----------+
// Id is primary key
```

// If test was dependent only on file then testId can be made a foreign key directly in here but test is dependent on build and that is one to many. (one test can run on many builds)

Test

```
    +------+--------------+
    | Id   | Test Name    |
    +------+--------------+
    | 1    | Test 1       |
    +------+--------------+
    | 2    | Test 2       |
    +------+--------------+
//Id is primary key
```

Build table

```
    +------+--------------+
    | S No | Build Number |
    +------+--------------+
    | 1    | Build_123    |
    +------+--------------+
    | 2    | Build_234    |
    +------+--------------+
// Id is primary key
```

BuildTestMap

```
+------+--------------+ ------- + ------ + --------+---------
| Id   | BuildId      | TestId | FileId | Executed | Passed |
+------+--------------+ -------+ -------+ -------- + -------
| 1    | Build_123    |  1     |  2    |   y       |  n     |
+------+--------------+ -------+ ------+ ----------+ -------
| 2    | Build_234    |  1     |  2    |   y       |  y     |
+------+--------------+------- + ------+ ----------+ -------

//Notice here TestId is foreign key of Test table and FileId is foreign key of File table and BuildId is foreign key of Build table
```

Answer (score 1):

Make build number as primary key in table 2 and in table 3 use it as foreign key.

Table 3 schema:

SRNo(Autoincrement),
Build number (ForeignKey from Table 2),
Testname (ForiegnKey from Table 1),
Executed,
Passed